# Filters are not filtering subnets in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

It's been my 4th day since I studied Terraform and I had a problem.
I have four subnet
[ Public-web-Public1, Public-web-Public2, Public-web-Private1, Public-web-Private2]
and i want to choose only 2subnets Public-web-Public 1,2
but it didn't work
also, I tried using tags instead of filters
but result is no matching subnet found too
i don't know why?
please can you help me?

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "test_subnet_ids" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"
}

data "aws_subnet" "test_subnet" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids)}"
        filter {
        name = "tag:Name"
        values = ["Public-web-Pub*"]
        }
  id    = "${tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids)[count.index]}"
}

output "subnet_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_subnet.test_subnet.*.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `test_subnet_ids`. No need for ``aws_subnet`, just to get the ids of your two subnets. But once you get the ids, you can then use` aws_subnet` to get full details of each subnet that was returned in your search.

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "test_subnet_ids" {

  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc1.id}"
  
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["Public-web-Pub*"]
  }  
  
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = data.aws_subnet_ids.test_subnet_ids.ids
}
```